# Angular 5 - worker_component_1 is undefined error after update from 4

Tags: angular

I have updated my Angular 4 app to version 5 with the following command:

```
npm install @angular/animations@'^5.0.0' @angular/common@'^5.0.0' @angular/compiler@'^5.0.0' @angular/compiler-cli@'^5.0.0' @angular/core@'^5.0.0' @angular/forms@'^5.0.0' @angular/http@'^5.0.0' @angular/platform-browser@'^5.0.0' @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@'^5.0.0' @angular/platform-server@'^5.0.0' @angular/router@'^5.0.0' typescript@2.4.2 rxjs@'^5.5.2'

npm install typescript@2.4.2 --save-exact
```

After that, I've also executed npm install and npm update commands. The app was working fine with Angular 4, but now I see this error in the browser console:

TypeError: worker_component_1 is undefined

Error details (nothing concrete)

> app.module.ts:18:35 ../../../../../src/app/app.module.ts
>   http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:29:1 **webpack_require**
>   http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:55:12 main.ts:4
>   ../../../../../src/main.ts http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:366:1
>   **webpack_require** http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:55:12 [0] http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:381:18 **webpack_require**
>   http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:55:12 webpackJsonpCallback
>   http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:26:23
>   http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:1:1

There is no compilation errors or warrnings.

Package.json file:

```
    {
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
 "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
 "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
 "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
 "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
 "@angular/forms": "^5.2.1",
 "@angular/http": "^5.2.1",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.1",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.1",
 "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.1",
 "@angular/router": "^5.2.1",
 "core-js": "^2.4.1",
 "jquery": "^3.3.0",
 "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
 "zone.js": "^0.8.20"
 },
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "^1.6.5",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.1",
"@angular/language-service": "^4.4.6",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"codelyzer": "^3.2.2",
"jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
"karma": "~1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.3",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.1.2",
"ts-node": "~3.2.0",
"tslint": "~5.7.0",
"typescript": "^2.6.2"
}
}
```

Comment: did you remove all of your node_modules before installing?

Comment: Before asking the question - no, but I've removed it now, installed once again and still the same error.

Comment: What does your `package.json` say? I don't think you upgraded correctly

Comment: Traditionally, people add any code to their question

Comment: I have added the code to question.